# React props syntax - having trouble passing reference to an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

(edited)
In the simple example below, I am having a heck of a time with the syntax for passing and accessing props that reference members of an array.

How is it that I should correctly address properties of an array of objects when passed as props?

I want to pass by reference, and I don't understand why I can't do it.

Thanks

```
// Define a type constant
const MyType {
    constructor( props ) { 
      this.state = {
        panelNumber : 0,
        panelDisplayMode : 'SINGLE'
      }
    } 
}

// create a collection of those type constants
class MyStore extends React.Component{

    MyCollection = [];

    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       var nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 123;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "SINGLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 456;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "DOUBLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 789;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "TRIPLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);           
    }

    // pass one of the instances (array) of the collection to a component.
    render () {
        <div>
          <MyComponent panel={this.MyCollection[2]}
        </div?
    }
}

// access one of the properties of the instance (array).
const MyComponent = props => (
    <div>
        <p>MODE:</p>{ props.panel.panelDisplayMode }
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

update your state with `setState` function, and map your collection array to pass single collection to your component. Something like this

```
class MyStore extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
       this.state = {
         MyCollection: [],
       }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
       var myCollection = [];
       var nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 123;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "SINGLE";
       myCollection.push(MyPanel);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 456;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "DOUBLE";
       myCollection.push(MyPanel);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 789;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "TRIPLE";
       myCollection.push(MyPanel);

       this.setState({MyCollection:myCollection});           
    }

    // pass one of the instances (array) of the collection to a component.
    render () {
        <div>
          {this.state.MyCollection.map(
            singleCollection=>{
               <MyComponent panel={singleCollection}>
            }
          )}
        </div>
    }
}
// access one of the properties of the instance (array).
const MyComponent = props => (
    <div>
        <p>MODE:</p>{ props.panel.panelDisplayMode }
    </div>
);
```

**Edit**

I ran this code after some fixing some syntax errors it works. Do you any specific error? By the way Here is the code

```
class MyType {
    constructor( props ) { 
      this.state = {
        panelNumber : 0,
        panelDisplayMode : 'SINGLE'
      }
    } 
}

// create a collection of those type constants
export default class MyStore extends React.Component{
    MyCollection = [];
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       var nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 123;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "SINGLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 456;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "DOUBLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 789;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "TRIPLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);           
    }

    // pass one of the instances (array) of the collection to a component.
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <MyComponent panel={this.MyCollection[2]}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// access one of the properties of the instance (array).
const MyComponent = props => {
    console.log("props ", props);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>MODE:</p>
            { props.panel.panelDisplayMode }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I restructured the example from using STATE to FIELD.  Does that clarify the question? I do not want to keep copying the data, but send the references.  And for some reason I can't address the properties of the class.

Answer (score 1):

State is immutable, so you shouldn't be trying to do `this.state.array.push`

Try:

```
this.setState({ 
    MyCollection: this.state.MyCollection.concat([MyPanel])
});
```

Edit: so after your edit, you should do something like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
       var nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 123;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "SINGLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 456;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "DOUBLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       nonsense = new MyType;
       nonsense.panelNumber = 789;
       nonsense.panelDisplayMode = "TRIPLE";
       this.MyCollection.push(nonsense);

       this.setState({ 
        MyCollection: this.state.MyCollection.concat([this.MyCollection])
       });  
    }
```

This will add the elements you added into your state (the array within your state, that is).

Comment: Sorry. I restructured the example from using STATE to FIELD.  Does that clarify the question?